# How to refresh the page after navigating to a different tab in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my home.js I have this code to navigate between the tabs. In the home page, the selected items should be added to my favourites which are displayed in the favourites tab. However, after I tap on the favourites tab, the added item is added only after I refresh the page. So,I want to refresh the page in the code as soon as I tap on the favourites in the navigation menu. What should go inside the onPress?

```
import Favourites from './favourites'
<Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Favourites"
        component={Favourites}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Favourites',
          tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <FAIcon
              onPress={
            //refresh Favourites here
        }
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
```

...

Comment: Are you fetching data from some api in Favorites screen?

Comment: Which navigation version u r using??

Comment: @KetanRamteke yes

Comment: you can use `useEffect` and run the fetch logic their.

Comment: @KetanRamteke thanks for your suggestion. I am a bit unsure of how I should call the useEffect from the home.js. I assume useEffect will be inside favourites.js.

Comment: `useEffect` will run by itself when the component is mounted for the first time. You don't need run it manually initially. later on, you can add dependencies to it on which it may be triggered.

Comment: @RajshekharYadav , I am using createMaterialBottomTabNavigator from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs'